# Search list not showing what I want it to show

Tags: php

I’m new to PHP and basically my issue is that I have a search function where I can search for products and the products do come up however it doesn’t have all the correct details I need. For example
A product can have more than 1 department assigned to it so when I try to search it only comes up with the first department so it looks like this: **D1 PS4 Games** console however it should look like this **D1, D2 PS4 Games console** I’m not sure how to fix this whether I change my select statement or something in my search controller

Comment: You need to post your code, and show what you've done to try to fix the problem for yourself. You also need to give more information about your database layout - for example is the department in a separate table (as it should be), or does your product have multiple columns for a fixed number of departments?

Comment: Welcome. "_I’m not sure how to fix this_" Neither do we, you know more than us, _you_ have the select statements and know what your code does. You can [edit] your question and paste relevant code/statements, you'll probably get more responses when we know what to deal with

Comment: What these gentlemen are trying to tell you is to provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass true, but please don't assume that everyone here is a "gentleman" :-).